# He's very good with children and no slouch around the house either/too

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, negation

*He's very good with children and no slouch around the house **either/too***

Which option either or too is grammatically correct here?

Comment: would anybody use **neither** here instead?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a word to modify or qualify the phrase "is no slouch". "No slouch" is an idiomatic negation that means "not lazy or incompetent". It describes the absence of a particular quality.

Generally, we don't use *too* to describe negations. *Too* indicates something added or extra, not the absence of something.

You should use *either*.

> #### either
>
> *adverb*
>
> **1:** LIKEWISE, MOREOVER —used for emphasis after a negative
>
> // not smart or handsome *either*
>
> **2:** for that matter —used for emphasis after an alternative following a question or conditional clause especially where negation is implied
>
> // who answers for the Irish parliament? or army *either*?
> — Robert Browning

(Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/either)

On the other hand, if we rephrased the sentence to remove the negation, then *too* would be the correct choice.

> He's very good with children, and works hard around the house *too*.

Comment: _who answers for the Irish parliament? or army either?_  Is any negation implied here?